# How this quantum tunneling formula is approximated?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling

Transmission coefficient '$T$' of a barrier of constant potential $V$ having length $a$ is approximated to $16\frac{E}{V}e^{-2qa}$ where $E<<V$ & $q=\sqrt{\frac{2m}{(\hbar)^2}(V-E)}$. $E$ is obviously the energy of the transmitted particle of mass $m$. But in most of the calculations (like Gamow's alpha emission theory) it is assumed that $T=e^{-2qa}$. How this last approximation is achieved? More specifically where does that term '$16\frac{E}{V}$' go?

Comment: How does the $16E/V$ appear in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a\gg b$, then
$$
a+b\approx a
$$

If $a\ggg b$, then $\log a\gg \log b$, which implies that
$$
ab\approx a
$$

If $a>\!\!>\!\!>\!\!> b$, then $\log a\ggg\log b$, which implies that
$$
a^{\log b}\approx a
$$
etc.

In nuclear physics $T$ is always a *very* small number (level 2 above), and therefore
$$
16\frac{E}{V}\mathrm e^{-2qa}\approx \mathrm e^{-2qa}
$$
because $\mathrm e^{-2qa}\lll 16\frac{E}{V}$.

A made-up example could be as follows:
$$
\left.\begin{aligned}
16\frac{E}{V}&\sim 10^{-3}\\
\mathrm e^{-2qa}&\sim 10^{-25}
\end{aligned}\quad\right\}16\frac{E}{V}\mathrm e^{-2qa}\sim 10^{-28}\approx 10^{-25}
$$
because in the end you are interested in $\log T$, and $28\approx 25$.